# NoMethodError in Cloths#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, for-loop

I am having trouble solving this problem. I keep getting the same error:

> (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):

Here my application.html

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %> 
<li><a><%= link_to 'category.title', category_cloth_path(@category)%></a></li>
<%end%>
```

cloths_controller.rb

```
def index
@cloths = Cloth.all
@categories = Category.all 
end

def show
@cloths = Cloth.all
@categories = Category.where("category_id = ?", @category.id)
@comments = Comment.where("cloth_id = ?", @cloth.id)
@comments = Comment.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
end
```

Comment: Can you clarify which line is giving the error?

Comment: <li><a><%= link_to 'category.title', category_cloth_path(@category)%></a></li> this line. it doesnt define the category id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a problem with your Routes.erb
if the problem (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass): exists that means your category_cloth_path(@category) is not defined in routes...
try putting in routes.erb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do    
resources :cloth
     member do
      get 'category'
     end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `@category` to `category`:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %> 
  <li><%= link_to category.title, category_cloth_path(category)%></li>
<%end%>
```

*Note:* `link_to` creates `<a></a>`, so you do not need to enclose `<%= link_to %>` within `<a></a>`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating links inside loop for each categories, so you must have to pass category inside link tag.

This might help you...

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %> 
<li><a><%= link_to 'category.title', category_cloth_path(category)%></a></li>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %> 
<li><a><%= link_to 'category.title', category_cloth_path(category)%></a></li>
<%end%>

def show
@cloths = Cloth.all
@categories = Category.find(params[:id])
@comments = Comment.where("cloth_id = ?", @cloth.id)
@comments = Comment.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using anchor tag (`<a>`) and also (link_to) you will get a link inside link, please remove the outer `<a>` tag.